# Forcing Binding Validation in WPF

Tags: c#, binding

I want to validate all the TextBox controls on the page load event. I'm aware of one method to do this. Here's what I used.

```
BindingExpression bx = myTextBox.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty );

if(bx != null)
    bx.UpdateSource();
```

I have a custom ValidationRule that checks if a field is required or not for some of my TextBoxes. Now if I run this code on the page load, it doesn't work. However, if I put this code into a button click event instead, then it works!

How do I validate my controls on a control load?

Comment: What doesn't work ? Is bx null at page load ?

Comment: bx does have a value at both the control load and the button click event. But on the control load the validation doesn't update without the help of the dispatcher. Not sure why since I'm executing on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the code inside a Dispatcher.Begininvoke

```
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
          BindingExpression bx = myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

          if (bx != null)
            bx.UpdateSource();
    }));
```

Comment: This works but do you have any explanation as to why? I'm not on a separate thread. The code being executed is running on the UI thread.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  I just know that some stuff isn't available when the Loaded event fires... apparently this is one of those cases.